# DoubleRenderError (Render and/or redirect and adding 'and return' at the end of redirect_to or self.render

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I have a messaging system every time I insert a message into the database. it insert duplicates im getting `AbstractController::DoubleRenderError (Render and/or redirect were called multiple times in this action)`. I tried to add **`and return`** at the end of redirect_to or `self.render` but it did not help. the problem it seems to be happening from the create method

```
# app/controllers/messages_controller.rb

class MessagesController < ApplicationController
   before_action :authenticate_user!
   before_action :set_conversation

  def index
    if current_user == @conversation.sender || current_user == 
      @conversation.recipient
      @other = current_user == @conversation.sender ? 
      @conversation.recipient : @conversation.sender
      @messages = @conversation.messages.order("created_at DESC")
    else
      redirect_to conversations_path, alert: "You don't have permission to view this."
    end
  end

  def create
    @message = @conversation.messages.new(message_params)
    @messages = @conversation.messages.order("created_at DESC")
    if @message.save
      ActionCable.server.broadcast "conversation_#{@conversation.id}", 
      message: render_message(@message)
      redirect_to conversation_messages_path(@conversation)
    end
  end

  private
  def render_message(message)
    self.render(partial: 'messages/message', locals: {message: message})
  end
  def set_conversation
    @conversation = Conversation.find(params[:conversation_id])
  end
  def message_params
    params.require(:message).permit(:context, :user_id)
  end
end
```

[This is an image from my terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jt9vD.png)

by removing

```
      ActionCable.server.broadcast "conversation_#{@conversation.id}", message: render_message(@message)
      redirect_to conversation_messages_path(@conversation)
```

it still insert duplicates messages

```
  def create
      @message = @conversation.messages.new(message_params)
      @messages = @conversation.messages.order("created_at DESC")
      @message.save
  end
```

[this image of terminal before removing from the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jt9vD.png)

[This an image from database show that it inserting duplicates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xD7E0.png)

[This new image from the terminal after i inserted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YifBa.png)

this is the view app/views/messages/index.html.erb

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3 text-center">
   <%= image_tag avatar_url(@other), class: "img-circle avatar-medium" %>
   <strong><%= @other.fullname %></strong>
   <%= link_to "View Profile", @other, class: "btn btn-default" %>
 </div>
<div class="col-md-9">
 <div class="panel panel-default">
   <div class="panel-heading">
    Conversation with <%= @other.fullname %>
    <input id="conversation_id" type="hidden" value="<%= 
    @conversation.id %>">
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
    <div class="container text-center">
      <%= form_for [@conversation, @conversation.messages.new], remote: true do |f| %>
          <div class="form-group">
            <%= f.text_field :context, placeholder: "Add a personal message", class: "form-control" %>
          </div>
          <%= f.hidden_field :user_id, value: current_user.id %>
          <div>
            <%= f.submit "Send Message", class: "btn btn-normal" %>
          </div>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="chat">
  <%= render @messages %>
</div>
```

Comment: I did update my question with the view .html.erb for the messages i dont have any javascript in there @SimpleLime

Comment: problem solved @SimpleLime On Rails 5, rails-ujs replaces jquery_ujs. Events will trigger twice if both are required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You call both `render` and `redirect_to` in the create method:

```
def create
  @message = @conversation.messages.new(message_params)
  @messages = @conversation.messages.order("created_at DESC")
  if @message.save
    ActionCable.server.broadcast "conversation_#{@conversation.id}", 
    message: render_message(@message) # <------ render here
    redirect_to conversation_messages_path(@conversation) # <-- redirect
  end
end

private
def render_message(message)
  self.render(partial: 'messages/message', locals: {message: message})
end
```

you can call only one of them - I'd advise to remove `render_message` or avoid using there `render` method. If you want to show a message after creation, you can use [Flash](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Flash.html).

Comment: it did not work for me i did remove both of them, it still inserted duplicates messages @mrzasa i did update my question with code i used

Comment: It apparently helped with error stated in the question title :). How do you check that messages are duplicated?

Comment: yes thank you it solved that error but i still not working i check from the database i update my question with image from database @mrzasa

Comment: Also i update the terminal image so u can see whats happening there @mrzasa

Comment: it looks that there are two requests sent (or the logs are duplicated). I'd debug the client (JS) side,

Comment: I did update my question with the view .html.erb for the messages i dont have any javascript in there @mrzasa

Comment: thank you so much that fixed my problem @mrzasa        On Rails 5, rails-ujs replaces jquery_ujs. Events will trigger twice if both are required.

// app/assets/javascripts/application.js
//= require jquery_ujs <-- delete this
//= require rails-ujs

Comment: it took me 2 weeks and i had to switch databases cause some told it  might be happening cause of sqlite so i switched to mysql  I really appreciated the help  @mrzasa

Answer (score 0):

If you have the error message "Render and/or redirect were called multiple times in this action....." as commented here, you are using redirect_to and render in the same action (create). That's clear!.

Now, I suggest you to just replace ***render*** with ***render_to_string*** in your method to find a possible solution to your problem.

```
def render_message(message)
  render_to_string(partial: 'messages/message', locals: {message: message})
end
```

Hope this helps. It works for me.

[image]

Source: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html